# No properties set in POST to spring @RestController

Tags: json, spring, spring-restcontroller

I have spring controller marked with `RestController`. If I do a POST with a Json object the properties of the model class `Company` are not populated, e.g. the `name` property is `null`.

If I reqeust the request body in the `save()` method I do get a Json string which has a name property, which means I'm sure that the json body of the POST request gets transmited.

Is there something I have to do to make spring deserialize the Json string into the `company` argument of the `save()` method?

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyResource {

    @Resource
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Company save(Company company) {
        return companyService.save (company);
    }

}
```

Company model class:
@Entity

```
public class Company {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    // public setters and getters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need @RequestBody annotation:

```
public Company save(@RequestBody Company company) {
    return companyService.save (company);
}
```